Physics Kinematics Equation $\Delta x = v_f\Delta t - \frac 12 a \Delta t ^2$ Derivation Using Calculus
I was wondering how you can derive the physics kinematics equation $\Delta x = v_f\Delta t - \frac 12 a \Delta t ^2$ algebraically. I understand where this equation comes from geometrically (when a=constant, v=linear, and $\Delta x$ is the area under the v-t curve from t=i to t=f which is in the shape of a trapezoid hence the formula).
How would you derive the formula algebraically? I read somewhere that you can rearrange the other kinematics equation $v_f=v_i+a\Delta t $ and integrate to obtained the desired aformentioned equation, but I do not know how to do this.
Any help in deriving $\Delta x = v_f\Delta t - \frac 12 a \Delta t ^2$ would be super helpful! Thanks so much!
p.s.-I initially posted this in Math Stack Exchange, but I later realized that this question topic would fit better in Physics Stack Exchange.

Well, any physics text book (say, on classical mechanics--either theoretical or experimentally of nature) should derive this relation. You should point out what exactly you don't understand. It is hard for us to guess what you know and what not, and why existing derivations don't suit you.

BTW: Why is there a minus sign in front of the acceleration term?

Because $v_F \Delta t$ is the displacement undergone if the final velocity were the velocity throughout the interval Δ. We need to subtract half the displacement that would be due to the extra velocity acquired over Δ if it were present over the whole of $\Delta t$. Because it is acquired steadily we need the $\tfrac 12$.

Derivation with calculus: $s''(t)=a \implies s'(t)=at+c , s(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}at^2+ct+d $ with $s'(0)=v_f;   c=v_f $ and $d=s(0)$

Are you familiar with calculus? Velocity is the rate of change of the position, and acceleration is the rate of change of velocity. This means that you can differentiate your equation of motion once to find the velocity as a function of time, and twice to find the acceleration as a function of time.
Since the fundamental theorem of calculus states that differentiation and integration "undo" or reverse each other, it follows that you can integrate your acceleration twice to get to the equation of motion.
An object in free fall accelerates at -9.81m/s². If you integrate that with respect to time, you get $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=at+C$$ where $C$ is the constant of integration, which in this case is $V_i$ (Velocity initial), and a is -9.81m/s². Imagine the velocity-time graph. $C" is telling you that you can move the graph up and down depending on your initial velocity.
If you integrate that, you get $$x=\dfrac{1}{2}at^2+V_it+C$$, where C is the initial position and Vi is the initial velocity.
What I showed is taking antiderivatives, applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and indefinite integrals. If any of this is confusing to you, you might want to brush up on your calculus.
The idea that the rate of change of position is just velocity should hopefully be clear to you!
